# Getting mismatched types error when i tried to assign numeric value to array object using pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, stl

I have initiated an array of 6 elements and tried to print it using a function called 'print'. I have used array object from the stl library. I passed the address of the array object to the print function. When I tried to change the value of the array object in the print function I am getting mismatched types error.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void print(array<int, 6> *arr){
    for(int i : *arr){
        cout<<i<<" ";
    }
    *(*arr+2)=2;
    cout<<endl;
}
int main(){
    array<int, 6> arr2={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    print(&arr2);
    print(&arr2);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error? Please extract a [mcve]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `*(*arr+2)=2;` you deference the `array` pointer and try to add `2` to it and then dereference that result to assign `2`. I *assume* you want to assign `2` to the element at index `2` in the `array`.

You do not need to use pointers here though, take the `array` by reference.

And, [never `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.).

```
#include <array>    // include the proper header files
#include <iostream>

void print(std::array<int, 6>& arr) {   // by reference
    for (int i : arr) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    arr[2] = 2;        // assign 2 to the element at index 2
    std::cout << '\n'; // std::endl flushes the stream which is usually uncessary
}

int main() {
    std::array<int, 6> arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    print(arr2);        // and don't take the array address here
    print(arr2);
}
```

---

If you *really* want to use a pointer here, this could be an option:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

void print(std::array<int, 6>* arr_ptr) {  // pointer
    if (arr_ptr == nullptr) return;        // check that it's pointing at something
    std::array<int, 6>& arr = *arr_ptr;    // dereference it

    for (int i : arr) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    arr[2] = 2;
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::array<int, 6> arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    print(&arr2);
    print(&arr2);
}
```

Comment: What is the issue in referencing the address from the main function?

Comment: @ash54321 No problem, just totally unecessary. If you send a pointer to the function you often need to check that you don't get a `nullptr` inside the function. By taking it by reference, you don't need to. I added an example to show how that could look.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
*(*arr+2)=2;
```

does not make a sense. For example the operator + is not defined for the class template std::array and as a result this expression `*arr+2` is invalid.

You could write

```
( *arr )[2] = 2;
```

or for example

```
*( ( *arr ).begin() + 2 ) = 2;
```

Comment: Oh, I was trying `*arr[2]`. I thought there was no need for parenthesis. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> *(*arr+2)=2;
> ```

Would be equivalent to

```
(*arr)[2] = 2;
```

*if* `arr` were a pointer to an array.  I assume that's what you are looking for.  But a `std::array` instance is *not* an array in that sense.  It is an object encapsulating an array, and emulating some of the properties of the underlying array, but it cannot be used interchangeably with the underlying array.  In particular, `std::array` objects do not decay to pointers as actual arrays do, and your code appears to be trying to rely on that.

You could instead do

```
*((*arr).data() + 2) = 2;
```

or, more idiomatically,

```
*(arr->data() + 2) = 2;
```

to leverage that array-to-pointer decay.  Or you could do

```
arr->data()[2] = 2;
```

. But none of those is as clear or straightforward as the ...

```
(*arr)[2] = 2;
```

... already mentioned, which is what you *should* do if you must work with a pointer to a `std::array` instead of a reference to one.

Answer (score 0):

**First** note that [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) has no `operator+`. So when you wrote the **expression**:

```
*arr+2 // INCORRECT
```

In the above expression, you are dereferencing the pointer to `std::array` and then adding `2` to the result. But as i said at the beginning, that there is no `operator+` for `std::array`, this expression is **incorrect**.

##### Limitation

**Second** you program has a limitation which is that the function `print` can accept a pointer to an `std::array` with **only** `6` elements. So if you try to pass a pointer to an `std::array` of some different size then your program won't work.

##### Solution

You can fix these by:

1. Passing the `std::array` **by reference**.
2. Using **templates**. In particular, using **template nontype parameter**.

The **advantage** of using template nontype parameter is that now you can call the function `print` with an `std::array` of different size as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<std::size_t N> 
void print(std::array<int, N> &arr){ //by reference
    for(const int &i : arr){
        std::cout<<i<<" ";
    }
    arr.at(2) = 2; //use at() member function so that you don't get undefined behavior
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
int main(){
    std::array<int, 6> arr2={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    print(arr2);
    
    std::array<int, 10> arr3 = {1,2,4,3,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    print(arr3);
}
```

Some of the modifications that i made include:

1. Removed `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and only included headers that are needed.
2. Used templates. In particular, removed the limitation by using **template nontype parameter**.
3. Passed the `std::array` by reference. That is, there is no need to pass a pointer to an `std::array`. We can just pass the `std::array` by reference.
4. Used `at()` member function so that we don't go out of bounds and so that we don't get undefined behavior.